# ubuntu installation getting stuck. i think my hard disk partition is corrupt

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive

Ubuntu installation getting stuck at where it asks for third party software and updates to be downloaded screen and hangs forever. I am using an hp laptop with original windows 7. I tried windows update but while installing updates power went off. Now windows is not loading. I ordered recovery dvd from hp. Windows installation also fails and gets stuck like Ubuntu. I ran hp diagnostics and ram and hdd, all tests passed.

Answer (score 0):

**Try Booting Back Into Ubuntu**

I assume you still have the usb or cd you used for attempting to install Ubuntu? If you don't, make another live cd or usb. Boot into your live usb/cd and try to copy all your data into another partition or another external drive. Unfortunately I don't know how to fix corrupted partitions, but I'd just format the partitions and try reinstalling Ubuntu or Windows.

I did a quick search on corrupt partitions, and I found this which seems to be pretty helpful:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370121

Best of luck to you!